# Glyphicons's look depends on from which server it is loaded

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Compare http://fiddle.jshell.net/R3qEn/6/ and http://fiddle.jshell.net/R3qEn/7/ - the only difference is first line of css-frame - from which server we import glyphicons.

Why I import it like this - because otherwise Firefox goes fully retarded with it.

Using last(31.0.1650.63 m) chrome on Windows 8.1.

[image]

Comment: I cant see any differences between the 2 fiddles, what browser are you viewing them in?

Comment: They look the same to me as well. Using chrome.

Comment: @JamesKing see update to my post please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you are not serving the needed resources to display Glyphicons (WOFF, TTF)

Check the network console and you'll see:

> GET glyphiconshalflings-regular.woff 404 Not Found
>
> GET glyphiconshalflings-regular.ttf 404 Not Found

Serve correctly this resources and you'll fix the issue.

Related: [WOFF Fonts, what Are they and why should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684256/woff-fonts-what-are-they-and-why-should-i-care)