# CSS Icon font in ASP.Net

Tags: html, asp.net, css, font-awesome-4

I am trying too use awesome CSS icon font in my ASP.net site.

I have imported the awesome.css in my website and also declared in

When I see my page I am getting output like below.

[image: Screen]

I wrote code for this is

```
<ol>
<li class="fa fa-home" title="Home"> Home</li>
</ol>
```

I am not getting where I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are referencing the fonts, but I think the problem is because you are not serving the needed resources to display Font Awesome fonts (WOFF, TTF).

Ref: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/

Serve correctly this resources and you'll fix the issue.

Related: [WOFF Fonts, what Are they and why should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684256/woff-fonts-what-are-they-and-why-should-i-care)